# pyqtgraph widget.addLine change color/width

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I want to use the widget function addLine. In my case it is as following:

```
widget.addLine(x=None, y=0.8) #endless horizontal line
```

Now i want to change the color and width of this line, but i cannot find a fitting function.

Is there something available to do this?

Additional, is there a similar function to "add a circle" instead of a line?

Comment: Can you provide an executable example of code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Changing the color and width of the line is simple enough using the `mkPen()` function.

As you have not provided all of your code here is a simple demo:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

y=[1,1,1,1,1]
pg.plot(y, pen=pg.mkPen('b', width=5))
```

Which draws a blue line with width 5. See the pyqtgraph documentation [here](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/functions.html#pyqtgraph.mkPen)

This would also work for the `addLine()` method you referenced in the question, e.g. `widget.addLine(x=None, y=0.8, pen=mkPen('r', width=3))`

As for your second question, looking at the pyqtgraph docs there doesn't appear to be a method that draws a circle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the parameters this way:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

data = [...]   
pg.plot(data, pen={'color':'w', 'width':1.5})
```